# Google developers console - unable to change auth credentials

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-oauth

I created a OAuth credential in app-engine for my android app using the steps provided here under "Create an Android Client ID"

https://cloud.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/enable_auth

This all works fine when developing using the debug key provided in the description. However, I now want to publish the app and need to change my sha1 code from the debug to production - I went to the client ID for the android app and the sha1 code is greyed out and wont allow me to change this. Is there any way to change this? Maybe a way in the terminal?

I already know that deleting the client ID and recreating it is NOT an option as for some reason this causes an error in the google developer console when trying to use the same android package name as a previously deleted one.

It seems crazy that there is no way to edit these settings. How am I going to publish my app without changing its packagename and creating a new clientID. There must be a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a new ClientID with the same package name but with a different sha1 code. I now have one for debug and one for production. Seems obvious now but Google could have made this clearer in the documentation